# LWC - Native share function not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I can't open the device native share option (navigator.share: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share). The function inside lightning returns me undefined. From Aura neither.
Do you know any workaround? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glls response is only 50% of the whole truth.

yes it is undefined - but why? Mainly because of Lockerservice which will also not allow to use the WebShare Api even for devices which supports it. That in returns mean that it is not available at all in lwc (no workaround) and not at all available in aura if the api version is >= 40 (workaround is to use a component with v.39 if that is no problem for you)

It doesn`t look like there are many polyfills so you are restricted to devices which supports it even with the aura workaround

Comment: Thank you so much! This works fine. 
If someone needs I will leave the instructions here:
* Create an aura component wrapping your lwc
* Set the aura component version to 39. (If you cant select '39' from developer console, try querying it)
* Send an event from lwc and call a method on you aura component that calls the navigator.share function.

Answer (score 2):

It returns undefined, because it is not supported. As stated in the documentation you linked:

> If the Web Share API is unsupported, then this method will be undefined.

Comment: Do you know any workaround? Thanks!